# Привязка обработчика события к ApplicationCommands.Open

Tags: .net, wpf

Пытаюсь добавить логику команды "Открыть" к RibbonButton в приложении WPF. В разметке xaml указана команда ApplicationCommands для кнопки, для команды сохранения указана привязка. При запуске приложения появляется ошибка: "Не удалось привести тип объекта System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo к типу System.Reflection.MethodInfo."Разметка и код приведены ниже. Просьба помочь с решением данной проблемы.

```xml
<ribbon:RibbonWindow.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding  Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Executed="{Binding Execute}" CanExecute="{Binding CanExecute}">

        </CommandBinding>
    </ribbon:RibbonWindow.CommandBindings>
<ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="OpenButton"
    LargeImageSource="Images/Open_16x16.png"
    Label="Open" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"/>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow, ICommand
    {
       ...
       public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
          {
              return (true);
          }
       public void Execute(object parameter)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Executed");
          }
       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам нужно просто

```
<CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
                Executed="Execute" CanExecute="CanExecute"/>
```

При этом ваши методы должны выглядеть так:

```
void Execute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = e.Parameter;
    // код
}

void CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = e.Parameter;
    // код
    e.CanExecute = true; // или false
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В таком виде появляется ошибка, что методы не найдены в классе MainWindow. Причём, насколько я помню, компилятор требовал методы, принимающие первым параметром MainWindow.

Comment: @AN90: Дополнил ответ, пробуйте.